# How to add multiple spaces in VS Code `window.title`?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to have more spacing between the two terms in the window title. But adding multiple spaces in `settings.json` `window.title` property does not work. It seems to treat multiple spaces as one.

```
"window.title": "${activeEditorShort}     ${rootName}",
```

I've also tried various workarounds without success:

- `&nbsp;`
- copy/pasting the Unicode non-breaking space U+00A0

I'm on a mac, not sure if it's the mac OS that is the problem, or VS Code.

Comment: is your name perhaps a reference to the UW mascot Bucky Badger?

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get this to work by using Unicode `em space` or `en space` characters. Those do not get "squashed" into a single space.

An example with 4 `em space`'s:

```
"window.title": "${activeEditorShort}    ${rootName}",
```

You can copy the unicode character inside the square brackets:

[ ] U+2003 em space (wider)

[ ] U+2002 en space (narrower)